# Sending value in jquery to php and returning page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I'm struggling on using simplemodal to load a edit textarea for my blog. I have it working lovely but i need to send a value somehow to the php page loading the content. Let me show the code and explain more.
Ok a tag to load the editor

```
<a class="blog_btns" id="edit" href="">Edit</a>
```

JQuery to load into simple modal window

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var contact = {
        message: null,
        init: function() {
            $('#edit').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // load the contact form using ajax
                $.get("../_Includes/edit.php", function(data) {
                    // create a modal dialog with the data
                    $(data).modal({
                        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
                        position: ["15%", ],
                        overlayId: 'contact-overlay',
                        containerId: 'contact-container',
                        onOpen: contact.open,
                        onShow: contact.show,
                        onClose: contact.close
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        open: function(dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeIn(200, function() {
                dialog.container.fadeIn(200, function() {
                    dialog.data.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $('#contact-container').animate({
                            height: h
                        }, function() {
                            $('#contact-container form').fadeIn(200, function() {
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        show: function(dialog) {
            //to be added later
        },
        close: function(dialog) {
            dialog.overlay.fadeOut(200, function() {
                $.modal.close();
            });
        },
    };
    contact.init();
});
```

The php page that loads the content and textarea

```
<?php
session_start();
define('HOSTNAME', '#');
define('DB_USERNAME', '#');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '#');
define('DATABASE', '#');
$link = mysql_connect(constant('HOSTNAME'), constant('DB_USERNAME'), constant('DB_PASSWORD')) or die("Database connection error, please check!");
mysql_select_db(constant('DATABASE'), $link) or die("Connection to the defined database not possible, please check!");
$sessionid = base64_decode($_SESSION['id']);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id=233 LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $tag_array = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE blog_id='$id' LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rtag = str_replace(' ', '', $row['tag']);
        $tag_array[] = $rtag;
    }
    $tag_array = implode($tag_array, ",");
}
?>
<div class="content">
    <div class="reply" style="display:none;"></div><form name="editblog" id="editblog" action="#" method="post"><font color="#FFF"><strong>Title: </strong></font><input name="blogtitle" id="blogtitle" type="text" id="title"  size="80" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
        <textarea cols="60" id="editblogbody" name="editblogbody" rows="20"><?php echo $body; ?></textarea><br />
        Please separate tages with a <strong>comma</strong>.<br />
        <font color="#FFF"><strong>Tags:</strong></font><input name="tags" id="tags" type="text" size="80" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $tag_array; ?>" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Post Blog" />
        <span id="blogFormProcessGif" style="display:none;"><img src="../_Images/loading.gif" width="28px" height="28px" alt="Loading" /></span></form>
    <script>CKEDITOR.replace("editblogbody");</script> </div>
```

So the window loads fine the content from the sql query works but i need to make the sql query dynamic by sending the blog id via the a link clicked at the start. i was thinking of using the rel attribute to return the value. i need to send this value to the php page for the sql query to load the correct blog somrthing like

```
$blogid = $_GET['blogig'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id='$blogid' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

but I'm racking my head to work out how to do it.

Can anyone help???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it in `rel` will work. Using `data-id="123"` and getting it using `$(this).data('id')` is better. Using the `href` is fine, e.g. `href="#123"`.

```
<a class="blog_btns" id="edit" href="#" data-id="123">Edit</a>
<a class="blog_btns" id="edit" href="#" rel="123">Edit</a>
<a class="blog_btns" id="edit" href="#123">Edit</a>
```

You the add this to the URL querystring

```
$('#edit').click(function(e) {
    var url="../_Includes/edit.php?blog_id=" + $(this).data('id');
    // var url="../_Includes/edit.php?blog_id=" + this.rel;
    // var url="../_Includes/edit.php?blog_id=" + this.href.replace('#', '');
    $.get(url, function(data){ 
        // etc
```

And get it in PHP using `$_GET['blog_id']`

**Please note** If there is more than one link to open an edit modal, using the id edit will not work, you will need to use a class.

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use a GET parameter in your jQuery `$.get()` , like:

```
"../_Includes/edit.php?blog_id=" + $('#edit').attr('rel')
```

you can get this value in php using something similar:

```
$_GET['blog_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

H i,

Within your function

```
  $('#edit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();         
            // load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("../_Includes/edit.php", function(data){ ...
```

You could send the id with

```
  $('#edit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();         
            // load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("../_Includes/edit.php?blogid=BLOGID", function(data){ ...
```

and php can pick it up as a regular parameter.

I am assuming that the page you are calling this function from knows what the blog id is , as it is the current page ?

On that, when PHP is rendering the page initially, it might be neat to add the blog id to the page body.

```
  <body id="BLOGID">
    ....
```

so now your function can grab it dynamically :

```
        $('#edit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();   

              var blogid = $("body").attr("id);

            // load the contact form using ajax
            $.get("../_Includes/edit.php?blogid="+blogid, function(data){ ...
```

or similar variation ..

??